# How do I reference what's stored in "timeElapsed" to compare in another function?

Tags: c++

Basically, I am wanting to take the time in seconds that's stored in the variable "timeElapsed" and use that for comparisons in another function to allow my program to output different things based on the time. However, I am completely unsure of how I can reference that local variable in another function, and global variables would not work since "timeElapsed" is reliant on other code in my setTimer() function.

Please help a lost student!

```
void setTimer() {
    int timeElapsed = 0;

    time_t beginTimer = time(NULL);

    timeElapsed = difftime(time(NULL), beginTimer);
```

Comment: Do you know how to pass arguments to functions? Hint: You've already done it four times in the code you've shown. Could you do it again for `timeElapsed`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide some more context to be able to help with this specific problem but you can access the timeElapsed a couple of ways.

If you were to pass in a value into set timer that is to be changed you can pass in a reference to a pointer and change the variable outside of your function

```
void setTimer(int *input) {
    
    int timeElapsed = 3;
    
    time_t beginTimer = time(NULL);
    timeElapsed = difftime(time(NULL), beginTimer);
    *input= timeElapsed; // Changes the compare variable in main
}

int main(){
    
    int compare = 5;
    setTimer(&compare);
    cout << compare; // This will now be the timeElapsed from setTimer
    return 0;
}
```

This is going to change whatever you pass in as 0 since

```
time_t beginTimer = time(NULL);
timeElapsed = difftime(time(NULL), beginTimer);
```

is going to make timeElapsed 0, but if you are trying to access a variable outside the scope of the function you can just pass in a variable you want to access, or return a value by changing `void setTimer()` to `int setTimer()` and returning `timeElapsed`